# Join Computer to Domain with Seperate Active Directory and DNS Servers

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller, internal-dns

I'm trying to understand how to join a client to a Windows domain that has a separate AD and DNS server.

I have installed one server with the AD role and one server with the DNS role.

Even if I configure my dns server to be authoritative on my domain but it doesn't work.

When I try to make a client join my ad domain I got an error like "dns name doesn't exist".

I read that it was probably about a replication issue but after few hours I really don't know how to figure this out.

My question is how do I join a non-AD integrated DNS server to a Windows domain (i.e. what DNS records do I need to add to the non-AD integrated DNS server for the DNS server to see the domain controller?). I understand the typical implementation is to have AD-integrated DNS for Windows domains, but this is a requirement for my work environment.

Comment: What configuration have you done on the DNS server? How are you populating AD specific records on it?

Comment: Why exactly do you want a non-AD DNS? There actually *are* several (although rare) use cases for it, but it's generally painful and not worth the hassle, unless you have very specific requirements preventing you from using a standard AD-integrated one.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are trying to join a computer to a Windows domain without the client knowing where the DNS server is. In a Windows domain DNS is typically AD-integrated. What that results in is when you join a computer to a Windows domain, some information is created in both AD and DNS. In order for a computer to find the domain controller during the join domain process, it has to know where the DNS server is.

The error

> When I try to make a client join my ad domain I got an error like "dns name doesn't exist".

means that your client cannot find a DNS server that knows the location of your domain controller. You can see which DNS records specifically it cannot find if you click the details button when the error takes place.

Make sure that your client is using the correct DNS server IP address before you try to join it to the Windows domain. Also verify that the DNS server is joined to the domain and contains the necessary records for the domain controller. After you do that try to join the client to the Windows domain.

Comment: In fact my dns server cannot join the AD domain, the popup says that the dns cannot find a domain controller. Do I need to add a A record matching my domain controller in the DNS tree ? Is it necessary to add the dns service role on the AD ?

Comment: You need an SRV record and an A record. If you click details when you have the error it will tell you which record it was not able to find. More information about the two records you need is available in [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758647%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) Microsoft TechNet article.

Comment: Hi jehutyy, did this work then?